# Comparing two groups: a risk of pseudoreplication

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample-size, experiment-design, ecology

I am growing coral on two different structures. I want to compare whether one structure (a table) grows coral more quickly than the other one (a tree). Both structures hold 60 pieces of coral, so a total of 120 pieces have been measured for their growth rate. Now I am wondering what to compare:

1. all 120 pieces and see if there is a significant difference between the two structures (without risking serious pseudo-replication?), or
2. just the average of the table and tree (no statistics, because in fact n = 1?).

I hope for (1), but I am scared that it is not scientifically valid.

Comment: This question seems clear to me. (Note that the issue of 'pseudoreplication' is discussed more in ecological settings than elsewhere, so people who work in other areas may be less familiar with it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you only have one replicate per treatment. If your question is: *Does the growth rate differ between* **the** *table and* **the** *tree?*, you are good to go. If you wanted to ask *Does the growth rate differ between tables and trees?*, you'll need more replicates of your treatments.

If it is possible, I would suggest breaking your 60 pieces of coral per treatment into sub-groups (e.g., 6 coral pieces each in 10 tanks). At a minimum, you'll need 3 sub-groups (e.g., three thanks per treatment), but more would be better. Also, if you're able to do this design, you'll need to worry about pseudoreplication. One method to deal with the pseudoreplication would be to treat each sub-group as a random-effect.

Comment: A bit late, but thanks for your answer!